# 予期しないAllowd memory sizeエラーについて

Tags: php, aws, laravel

Webシステム上にて発生しているAllowd memory sizeエラーについて、解決の糸口を掴みたいです。

**環境**
Service: ECS FARGATE
Docker image: php:7.2.34-apache
Framework: Laravel 5.6
Database: 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.1

**メッセージ**

```
EXCEPTION Allowed memory size of 6442450944 bytes exhausted (tried to
> allocate 139968446450312 bytes)
```

**発現箇所**
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php`
等複数箇所

**頻度**
2~4回/月 ほど

同一TASK上で一度発生すると、すべてのリクエストで発生し、かつ自力では復旧できなくなってしまいます。
opcache_reset()をすると治ることは確認していますので、何かしらの要因でopcacheが壊れていると推測しています。

システムは数年運用しておりますが、上記現象は確認しておらず、ここ２ヶ月ほどで見られるようになりました。

根本解決の糸口がつかめず参ってしまっています。
なにか確認すべき事象や、ナレッジを共有いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まずはエラーメッセージでそのまま検索してみましょう。恐らく使用できるメモリを使い切っているのが原因で、php.ini 等でメモリ割当量を増やすか、コードを修正する形になりそうです。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。エラーメッセージ自体の内容は把握しておりますが、`tried to allocate 139968446450312 bytes` とあるように、140TBほどを要求されており、php.iniでの対応は考えておりません。おそらくどこかのコードがopcacheを壊していると思いますが、その検討がついておりません。どのようなコードだとopcacheが壊れてこのようになってしまうか、ご知見ありましたら教えていただけると幸いです

Comment: 必要とされるメモリ量が尋常な容量ではないですよね。もし対外的に公開しているサーバ上でその現象が生じているなら、何らかの攻撃である可能性を疑います。イントラネットに閉じていて社外から使われることはないサーバならバグも疑いますが、どっちでしょう？

Comment: VPC自体は閉じられていませんが、SubnetはPrivateに設定されているので、社外からは直にTASKに対してアクセスはできないはず。。ではあります

Comment: 上記追記：ECSEXECならアクセスは可能な状態です。IAM周りは念のため確認してみます。ただ、頻度が低いことと、脅迫の類は無いこと、復旧自体は難しくないことから、攻撃の可能性は薄いと考えております。